# $S$ is a vector subspace of vector space $V$? (matrix in complex)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, matrix-equations

$V = M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$, $K = \mathbb{C}$ and

$$ S = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{pmatrix} \in V : a_{ij} = \overline{a_{ji}}\text{ for } i, j = 1, 2 \right\} .$$

*I'd like to understand better how to work with complex and matrix to check this question.
I know there are 3 rules, but id like how to apply in cases like that. Thanks in advance, ill be glad for explanations.*

Answer (score 1):

For $i \in \{1,2\}$, $\overline{a_{ii}} = a_{ii}$ implies that $a_{ii}$ is a real number, so
$$S = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x & z \\ \overline{z} & y \end{pmatrix} \in V : x,y \in \mathbb R \textrm{ and } z \in \mathbb C \right\}.$$
Now, is the sum of two matrices in $S$ a matrix in $S$? and the scalar multiplication of a matrix in $S$ with a complex number?

Comment: Sorry, but it isnt "ii".

Comment: I mean, since $\overline{a_{11}} = a_{11}$ and $\overline{a_{22}} = a_{22}$, $a_{11}$ and $a_{22}$ are real numbers. For $a_{12}$ and $a_{21}$ it is not guaranteed, only that $a_{21} = \overline{a_{12}}$.

Comment: thanks for helping, im understanding better through you answer, im not sure, but i is'nt the inverse? Like, $$\text {i=1, j=2}  \text { so } a_{ij} = \overline{a_{ji}} \text { or } a_{12} = \overline{a_{21}}$$, so theses are the reais number, because they dont have the imaginary part?